# Laravel API Authentication

Tags: api, authentication, laravel-5.1

I am building an API using Laravel which will be used by both my Mobile and Web Applications. I am confused regarding authentication.

Basically the web application will be used by users both in logged in state and visitor state.

How would authentication work in that case? If the API uses username/password to authenticate a user what about visitors?

Also, how do I make sure its the webapp and mobile app thats making a request to the API? How do I ensure that someone doesn't programatically doesn't access the API and its only my apps that can request access to data?

Answer (score 0):

You have a routes file, and you will be able to apply a filter (Laravel 4) / middleware (Laravel 5) to those routes to protect them. Assuming that you are using L5 -

```
Route::group('api/v1', function() {

   Route::group(['middleware' => 'api.auth'], function() {
     Route::get('protected', function() {
       return response()->json(['Authenticated Response'], 200);
     });
   });

   Route::get('guest', function() {
     return response()->json(['Guest Response'], 200);
   });
});
```

Then you would need to create a middleware for `api.auth` - See http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-group-middleware and http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware

So what happens now is when you try to visit `/api/v1/protected`, Laravel will run the `api.auth` middleware before it lets the user go any further.

`api/v1/guest` will of course be able to be accessed by authenticated users and guest users because there is no middleware applied.